# Creating a left justified table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am attempting to create table and justify the table to the left of the page with the caption also to the left. I have used the below code however this moves the table to the left but the caption remains centred. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Tables}

\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{flushleft}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc} 
     \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
     $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      1 & 1110.1 & a\\
      2 & 10.1 & b\\
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{centred table}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en) package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false}

\begin{document}

\section{Tables}

\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{flushleft}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc} 
     \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
     $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      1 & 1110.1 & a\\
      2 & 10.1 & b\\
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{centred table}
  \end{flushleft}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]